# My water simulation (preview) outline is not clear?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, workflow, fluid-simulation

I am a newbie to Blender, I have followed a tutorial (Blender Guru) on how to make a water simulation. The water has a dark outline instead of being completely clear!

I have set this test render on 20 samples. What have i done wrong? The background is the lighting so maybe the background needs to be brighter/darker?

Is it supposed to be like this? Any help is appreciated!

This was made in cycles render engine, the final render will be on 450 samples..

[image]

set my enviernmont texture and used the background as the texture. how is this?

[image]

Comment: Likely your material settings for the fluid shader. Can you post your blend file?

Comment: Sure, Todd. finally added the .blend file :)

Comment: It looks better.

Comment: well, i say it is safe to say that this problem has been resolved, i am now closing it.

Comment: You can upvote my answer if you felt I helped at all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just needed more lighting. The water was reflecting your black background, so thats what you see.

I just added an HDRI and it seems to look a little better.

[image]

Comment: Well, i don't know what an HDRI is, or how to add one..but i did change the world color to be white..now the water outline is white..

Comment: hmm..how else could i fix this Ic

Comment: HDRI is a 360 degree picture that you can use to light your scene. I suggest you read this http://noemotionhdrs.net/index.html You dont need to use a HDRI, just add more lights to your scene. You just have your background picture as the light source and everything else is black.

Comment: after adding two "point" lights as they are called, i still do not see a difference. the water still reflects the world lightning

Comment: forgot to tag you lol

Comment: Its going to be hard to get it to look correct because you don't have much in the scene for the water to reflect (so it will just be black or white). Maybe try duplicating your image a few times and move them around until the water looks how you want it to. Just make sure they are out of the camera view. Also try sun lamps instead see if that helps anything.

Comment: so basically duplicate the background image all around the scene to make a cube then it won't reflect anything then the background image?

Comment: pretty much. It doesnt have to make a perfect cube but just enough so the water isnt reflecting black everywhere. Again though, an HDRI is still the best choice. Get a free one here https://hdrihaven.com/index.php and watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI_FMa-8w50

Comment: thanks for the vid. but there is no nodes for my world in the node editor even after a add "use nodes"

Comment: Not sure why that would be. If you want to use an HDRI maybe ask it as a seperate question.

Comment: view the edit..

Comment: maybe i could find a water background and set it as a environment texture